# Spli tarz file not extracting on Linux

Tags: linux, ftp, corrupt

I have transferred large tarz ~17Gb using gnu split in windows with 2048mb parts,
After uploading to Linux (Redhat 5 32bit) and combining the files using cat (cat xaa xab xac ... >> final.tarz), there is an error during checking tar xvfz final.tarz.

`gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
 tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

The file size are ditto and also the md5 checksum. So no clue what went wrong.

Can I resume tar from another part or skip the bad part, or may be check if the files are correctly transferred and re-transfer bad files only.

Comment: No, you cannot. Perhaps build again the `tar.gz` archive on source host, split the `.tar.gz` file again, compute some checksum of the splitted parts (e.g. with `md5sum`) both on source and destination machines (of course transfer again those with a mismatch).... Also check with `tar tzvf` that the final reconstructed file is good. Alternatively use [afio](https://freecode.com/projects/afio) to make the archive - it has a more robust format

Comment: What kind of files do your archive contain?

Comment: The files are binary i.e. database and jboss files.